# Open sets and intersections

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $G$ is an open subset of the real number that is not upper bounded. Is there a real number $x > 0$ such that the set of all integer multiples of $x$ intersects $G$ at infinitely many points?

That is, is it true that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{mx\mid m\in \mathbb{Z}\}\bigcap G$ is infinite?

My intuition tells me yes, since the fact that $G$ is not upper bounded seems to be a major factor here, but I can’t seem to prove it.

Comment: Is $G$ a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: Yes, I made an edit to the question I asked. It should be slightly clearer now.

Comment: i think its, $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ does $\exists~ (x \in \mathbb{R}) > 0 ~s.t~ A = \{ax | a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with $A \cap G$ being infinitely large.

Comment: What is your proof

Comment: If x was rational in the question, answer was no.

Comment: just spitballing here, but if such an x exists, and since the Reals are a well ordered chain, couldnt you just use open balls around x to make a countable ordering?

Comment: Where is $G$ being open used here?

Comment: It's false if $G$ isn't open. Let $G=\{c^k, k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with $c > 1$ and $c$ transcendental. 

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}, p>q, m>n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $px = c^m$ and $qx = c^n$. Then $\frac{p}{q} = c^{n-m}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: $G$ is open means $G$ is a countable union of open intervals. If $(a,\infty ) \subset G$ or $G$ admits a subsequence of open interval with bounded below diameter, things are easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Suppose $\nexists x$ such that $\{nx:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cap G$ is infinite, then for any $\epsilon>0$, $\{n\epsilon:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cap G$ is finite.

Let $n_0 = \max \{n \in\mathbb{Z}:n\epsilon \in G\}$.

Take $a\in G$ such that $a > n_0\epsilon$. $[\because G$ is unbounded above$]$.

Let $S = \{x \in G: (a,x) \subset G\}.$ $S\ne \phi$ as $G$ is open.

Let $b=\sup S$.

So $(a, b) \subset G$. Then $|b-a|<\epsilon$ also implies $b=a$. We have arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: Would you mind to suggest how does $|b-a|<\epsilon$ imply $b=a$?

Comment: As $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small.

Comment: As you choose $n_0$ you implicitly fix an $\epsilon$ already, thus your $a$ and things else too depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: I understood the problem with $\epsilon$. There is a glitch in the proof. I'll try to mend it.